# How to browse through file lines with Julia

Tags: julia

I need to browse through a file lines and check if a substring exists inside that line , I need to have the option to go through lines by thier original order..

eachline won't help me from what I understand since I will loose the order,What method should I be using that best fit's my needs ?

Comment: What makes you think `eachline` loses the order? The purpose of `eachline` is to iterate over all the lines from the first to the last, isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks, though is there some method you can use index in order to chose line number and extract it's content ?

Comment: You can use readlines to give you the lines in a file as an array of strings. `lines = readlines("myfile.txt")`. You can index into said array to get a particular line. `lines[5]` gets you the content of the 5th line.